# Multiple numerical integrations and green's functions propagation of the solution

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

I have to solve a system of equations where the coefficients have to be computed from numerical integrations. My problem is that my codes is to extremely slow because I each time that it has to compute a values re-compute all the numerical integrations that it needs, instead taking the values that it already computed in advance.

Basically I defined some functions from which I need to compute the coefficients of my system:

```
Z[phi_] := HeavisideTheta[phi - phim] - HeavisideTheta[phi - phiM]

L[t_, eps_] := eps*HeavisideTheta[Sin[wd*t]]

Gj[phi_, t_, phi0_, w_, j_, di_] := 
 1/(2*Pi) + 1/Pi*Exp[-j^2*di*t] Cos[j*phi0]*Cos[j*(phi - w*t)] + 
  Sin[j*phi0] Sin[j*(phi - w*t)]

DGj[phi_, t_, tau_, phim_, phiM_, w_, j_, di_] := 
 Gj[phi, t - tau, phim, w, j, di] - Gj[phi, t - tau, phiM, w, j, di]

cj[phi_, tau_, t_, w_, phim_, phiM_, di_, j_]= Integrate[DGj[phi_, t_, tau_, phim_, phiM_, w_, j_, di_],tau]

    Qj[phi_, w_, phim_, phiM_, T_, di_, 
  j_] := -2*cj[phi, 0, T, w, phi, phiM, di, j] + 
  cj[phi, T, T, w, phi, phiM, di, j] + 
  cj[phi, T/2, T, w, phi, phiM, di, j]
```

now I need to compute the coefficients of my system:

```
Aj[j_, w_, di_, 
  T_] := (1/Pi) NIntegrate[
   Exp[-j^2*di*T]*Cos[j*phi1]*Cos[j*(phi1 - w*T)], {phi1, 0, 2*Pi}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 7]
Bj[j_, w_, di_, 
  T_] := (1/Pi) NIntegrate[
   Exp[-j^2*di*T]*Cos[j*phi1]*Sin[j*(phi1 - w*T)], {phi1, 0, 2*Pi}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 7]
Cj[j_, w_, di_, 
  T_] := (1/Pi) NIntegrate[
   Exp[-j^2*di*T]*Sin[j*phi1]*Cos[j*(phi1 - w*T)], {phi1, 0, 2*Pi}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 7]
Dj[j_, w_, di_, 
  T_] := (1/Pi) NIntegrate[
   Exp[-j^2*di*T]*Sin[j*phi1]*Sin[j*(phi1 - w*T)], {phi1, 0, 2*Pi}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 7]
q1j[phim_, phiM_, j_, w_, di_, 
  T_] := (1/Pi) NIntegrate[
   Exp[-j^2*di*T]*
    Cos[j*phi1]*(Qj[phi1, w, phim, phiM, T, di, j] + 1/(2*Pi)), {phi1,
     0, 2*Pi}, AccuracyGoal -> 7]
q2j[phim_, phiM_, j_, w_, di_, 
  T_] := (1/Pi) NIntegrate[
   Exp[-j^2*di*T]*
    Sin[j*phi1]*(Qj[phi1, w, phim, phiM, T, di, j] + 1/(2*Pi)), {phi1,
     0, 2*Pi}, AccuracyGoal -> 7]

c1j[phim_, phiM_, j_, w_, di_, 
  T_] := ((1 - Aj[j, w, di, T])*(1 - Dj[j, w, di, T]) - 
     Bj[j, w, di, T]*Cj[j, w, di, T])^(-1)*((1 - Dj[j, w, di, T]) q1j[
      phim, phiM, j, w, di, T] + 
    Bj[j, w, di, T]*q2j[phim, phiM, j, w, di, T])
c2j[phim_, phiM_, j_, w_, di_, 
  T_] := ((1 - Aj[j, w, di, T])*(1 - Dj[j, w, di, T]) - 
     Bj[j, w, di, T]*Cj[j, w, di, T])^(-1)*((Cj[j, w, di, T]) q1j[
      phim, phiM, j, w, di, T] + (1 - Aj[j, w, di, T])*
     q2j[phim, phiM, j, w, di, T])
```

that defined all the parameters are all of them just numbers.
Now I need compute the solution of my problem as:

```
 fj[phi_, w_, phim_, phiM_, T_, di_, 
   j_] := (Qj[phi, w, phim, phiM, T, di, j] + 1/(2*Pi)) + 
   Cos[j*(phi - w*T)]*c1j[phim, phiM, j, w, di, T] + 
   Sin[j*(phi - w*T)]*c2j[phim, phiM, j, w, di, T]; 
f[phi_, w_, phim_, phiM_, T_, di_, Jmax_] := 
  Sum[(fj[phi, w, phim, phiM, T, di, j], {j, 1, Jmax}];
```

moreover I would love to propagate in time this function using my green's function, I do it propagating each j-component and after that I will sum it all:

```
p1j[t_, phi_, w_, phim_, phiM_, T_, di_, j_] := 
 NIntegrate[
   Gj[phi, t, phi1, w, j, di]*
    fj[phi1, w, phim, phiM, T, di, j], {phi1, 0, 2*Pi}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 7] + 
  NIntegrate[
   L[tau, eps]*(1/(2*Pi))*
    DGj[phi, t, tau, phim, phiM, w, j, di], {tau, 0, t}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 7]

p1[t_, phi_, w_, phim_, phiM_, T_, di_, Jmax_] := Sum[p1j[t_, phi_, w_, phim_, phiM_, T_, di_, j_], {j, 1, Jmax}]
```

I guess that conceptually it is correct just I feel that it takes too much time! like to see the results I do:

```
sol = Table[f[i, w, phim, phiM, T, di, Jmax], {i, 0, 2*Pi, 0.1}];
ListPlot[sol]
```

and for all the times:

```
hMap = Table[
   p1[t, phi, w, phim, phiM, T, di, Jmax], {phi, 0.1, 2*Pi, 0.1}, {t, 
    0.1, 24.2, 1}];
ListContourPlot[hMap]
```

this takes order of 10 hours!

I guess in this way the code basically each time needs to solve all the coefficients so it takes a lot of time (order of 10 hours)!

does someone know how to solve this problem? 
thank you very much!

Comment: That's a lot of code! I wonder if you could reduce your problem to a more manageable minimal working example.

Comment: All that code and it's still not evaluatable - all the constants `{w, phim, phiM, T, di, Jmax}` are undefined, several of your functions have underscores on the right side of the equal sign.